# Windows error in os.listdir()

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm writing my first Python script to do some cross-platform work and have bumped into an error I didn't expect and can't find any information about (or maybe I don't understand what I'm reading).

```
brand_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Resources', 'html', brand )
for f in os.listdir(brand_dir):
  # BREAKS WITH: cannot find the file path specified: 
  # 'C:\\path\\to\\Resources\\html\\brand_value/*.*'
```

Works fine on OSX. The only part that looks weird is the `/*.*` so I'm kind of working under the loose assumption that it's the problem, but I don't see any indication that this should throw Python for a loop.

I'm sure this is a rookie mistake, but what is it? Python 2.7.3, Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: I'm having this problem, too: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/numenta-ci/nupic/build/0.0.1.14#L1545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that `C:\\path\\to\\Resources\\html\\brand_value` is a valid path on your system? The `/*.*` part is quite normal, when Windows couldn't find the path, it occurs.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's the obvious thing, but the path definitely exists.

Comment: I tried your code on my Win7 with Python2.7.3 and it works. There might be some privilege limitation for Python to visit that directories?

Comment: Looks like this was either a me problem or a temporary system issue. I just got back to it and it seems to work now. I have no idea what I was doing before, but the time delta is too much to spend any cycles worrying about it. Thanks.